# How do I get my method to acumulate when posted in a different class?

Tags: java

I have a variable to track total time that needs to accumulate after each ticket.

I have it working in the main class, but it has to go in another class too, and I can't figure out how to do that.

It works like this in the main method:

```
double totalTimeSpent = 0;

double spent = ticket1.getTimeSpent()+ totalTimeSpent;
System.out.println("Gerapporteerde tijd in minuten: " + ticket1.getTimeSpent());
System.out.println("Totale tijd = "+ spent + " minuten");
totalTimeSpent = spent;
```

When I try to make a method in a different class it doesn't accumulate, but just takes the TimeSpent for that particular Ticket:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp; import java.util.Scanner; import java.io.*;

class TicketGegevens{

private long startTime;
private long endTime;
private int ticketNummer;
private String behandelaar;
private int kanaalTicket;


public void setBehandelaar(String behandelaar){
    this.behandelaar = behandelaar;
}

public String getBehandelaar(){
    return behandelaar;
}

public void setTicketNummer(int ticketNummer) {
    this.ticketNummer = ticketNummer;
}

public int getTicketNummer(){
    return ticketNummer;
}

public void setKanaalTicket(int kanaalTicket){
    this.kanaalTicket = kanaalTicket;
}

public int getKanaalTicket(){
    return kanaalTicket;
}

public void tijdStempelStart(long startTime){
    this.startTime = startTime;
    Timestamp startTijd = new Timestamp(startTime);
    System.out.println("Starttijd ticket is: " + startTijd);
}

public void tijdStempelEind(long endTime){
    this.endTime = endTime;
    Timestamp eindTijd = new Timestamp(endTime);
    long timeSpent = this.endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Eindtijd ticket is: " + eindTijd);

}

public double getTimeSpent(){
    return (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0 / 60.0;
}
// here is where I want my new method to be:
public double getTotalTimeSpent(){
  }
}

class WriteFile{

private String path;
private boolean append_to_file = false;

public WriteFile(String file_path) {
    path = file_path;
}

public WriteFile( String file_path , boolean append_value) {
    path = file_path;
    append_to_file = append_value;
}

public void writeToFile(TicketGegevens stempel) throws IOException {


    FileWriter write = new FileWriter( path , append_to_file);
    PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter( write );

    print_line.printf( "%s" + "%n" , "Ticketnummer: " + stempel.getTicketNummer());
    print_line.printf( "%s" + "%n" , "Behandelaar: " + stempel.getBehandelaar());
    print_line.printf( "%s" + "%n" , "Kanaal: " + stempel.getKanaalTicket());
    print_line.printf( "%s" + "%n" , "Tijd in minuten: " + stempel.getTimeSpent());
    print_line.printf( "%s" + "%n" , "Cummulatieve tijd: "); //+ stempel.getTimeSpent());
    print_line.println(" ");

    print_line.close();
}
}

class nieuwTicket{

public void startNieuwTicket(){
    System.out.println("Toets enter om een nieuw ticket te starten.");
    try
    {
        System.in.read();
    }  
    catch(IOException e)
    {}  
}   
}

class TicketTracker{

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    int i=0;
    double totalTimeSpent = 0;
    while (i<999){

    TicketGegevens ticket1 = new TicketGegevens();

    System.out.println();
    ticket1.tijdStempelStart(System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Hier start de tijdmeting 
    System.out.println();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "Voer het ticketnummer in (Alleen hele nummers):");
    ticket1.setTicketNummer(keyboard.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Wie is de behandelaar(voer naam in):");
    Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userName=keyboard2.nextLine();
    ticket1.setBehandelaar(userName);
    System.out.println( "Hoe is de ticket binnengekomen? ");
    System.out.println( "Kies 1 voor Mail, 2 voor Telefoon, 3 voor Software en 4 voor overig:");
    ticket1.setKanaalTicket(keyboard.nextInt());


    System.out.println();

    //Hier eindigt de meting
    ticket1.tijdStempelEind(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println();

    //Een samenvatting van de gegevens
    System.out.println("Samenvatting:");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Het ticketnummer is:" + ticket1.getTicketNummer());
    System.out.println("Opgepakt door: " + ticket1.getBehandelaar());
    System.out.printf("Binnengekomen via: " + ticket1.getKanaalTicket());

        switch(ticket1.getKanaalTicket()){
            case 1: 
                System.out.println(" Mail ");
                break;
            case 2: 
                System.out.println(" Telefoon ");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println(" Software ");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(" Overig");
                break;
        }       

    double spent = ticket1.getTimeSpent()+ totalTimeSpent;
    System.out.println("Gerapporteerde tijd in minuten: " + ticket1.getTimeSpent());
    System.out.println("Totale tijd = "+ spent + " minuten");
    totalTimeSpent = spent;

    //Hier worden de gegevens weggeschreven naar een textbestand.
    WriteFile writeToFile = new WriteFile("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\time.txt", true);
    writeToFile.writeToFile(ticket1);

    //Hierna start een nieuw ticket.
    nieuwTicket ticket2 = new nieuwTicket();
    ticket2.startNieuwTicket();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: please provide the Ticket class.

Comment: Maybe its a good idea to provide everything you have. Because to me its not really clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I posted my whole code... the thing is that it works in the main method (to acumulate the time of the ticket), but not if I make it a method in the class "TicketGegevens", then it doesnt acumulate.

Comment: How should it work? Do you want to set start time and then end time on that instance and then later on use the same instance and overwrite start and end time and accumulate it with total time in that instance?

Comment: Note: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names should be written in PascalCase, and variable and method names should be written in camelCase. For instance, `file_path` should be `filePath` and `nieuwTicket` should be `NieuwTicket`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. When I execute the code I get the right respons: Gerapporteerde tijd in minuten: 0.12766666666666668(=one ticket)
Totale tijd = 0.21150000000000002 minuten(=all the tickets together). I just dont get the total time in my textfile. I am too much of a rookie to get it working. I have tried the solution you said, but I cant get it working.

Comment: just make ur instances track its individual times and externally calculate everyting together.